# sql server select column

Tags: sql-server, select

What is the difference between

```
 1).
 SELECT
      e.name 'name',
      e.age  'age'
 FROM
 Employee e

 2).
 SELECT
      e.name name,
      e.age  age
 FROM
 Employee e
```

Comment: Please use the `[sql-server]` tag instead of a separate `sql` and `server` - thank you!!

Comment: I dont know!! why u ask this. Both are same!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first you are qualifying the column aliases as strings, in the second you are not.

Functionally, they are the same.

They would product the same result as:

```
SELECT
   e.name,
   e.age
FROM
Employee e
```

Answer (score 2):

e.g. if you like to use column names with space, special characters or reserved SQL words you need qualifying. Otherwise the quotes are optional.

```
SELECT
  e.name 'first name'
  ...
```